# Importing Qt Studio Project in a Qt Creator QML app

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-creator, qt-design-studio

I have created a hello world project in Qt Design Studio. Now I need to import QtDS project tree/directory in QtQuick qml app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official documentation about this topic is in [doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/quick-converting-ui-projects](https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/quick-converting-ui-projects.html). Assuming still this cannot work for you. You can check this post in the Qt forum: [how-to-use-qmlproject-ui-qml-forms-from-design-studio-in-qt-creator-pro-project](https://forum.qt.io/topic/126056/how-to-use-qmlproject-ui-qml-forms-from-design-studio-in-qt-creator-pro-project/2).

So in order to resume the information:

1. Set all your *.ui.qml files from Qt DS project to a separate *qrc.
2. Import the new *qrc into your Main Qt Project.

Comment: Thanks, let me check the solution